# Is it possible Emacs automate to do many steps after restart Emacs?

Tags: init-file

Given:

```
Linux Mint 20.2
Emacs 27.1
3 monitors
```

After restart Emacs I every time do the next steps:

```
1. make-fram-on-monitor (in full screen mode) -> DP1
2. make-fram-on-monitor (in full screen mode) -> DP2
3. make-fram-on-monitor (in full screen mode) -> DP2

4.Switch to monitor DP1 and do the next steps:

4.1. tab-new
4.2. Open dired-mode.
4.3. Go to folder /home/myuser/dev/myProject
4.4. M-x vterm
4.5. M-x rename-buffer  -> my_buffer_name
4.6. tab-new
4.7. M-x shell



5. Switch to monitor DP2 and switch to buffer *scratch*

6.Switch to monitor DP3 and do the next steps:
 6.1. tab-new
 6.2. Open dired-mode.
 6.3. M-x find-file "to.do.org"
 6.4. tab-new
 6.5. M-x find-file "my.work.org"
```

To do this every time after restart Emacs **is not very convenient**. It's routine work.
So the quesion is:
Is it possible Emacs automate to do all this steps after restart Emacs? Or I need to write little script (e.g. myBoot.el) and Emacs will start it every time after restart?

Comment: Are you just asking how to use an init file?

Comment: Could you record those steps as macro, save the macro and bind it to a key?

Comment: @Drew No, I just asking what is the best solution for this

Comment: @rsp Is it possible to record so many steps (with 3 monitors) to keyboard macro?

Comment: @a_subscriber I could not find a reference to a maximum size for Emacs keyboard macros. Have a look at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacrosTricks to get you started.

Comment: @rsp Do you think that macros is the best solution?

Comment: Define "for this". Questions asking for the "best" solution encourage opinion-based answers, and are typically closed for that reason.

Comment: @Drew Avoid to do routine work every time

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for DP1.  You can `M-x my/init` after your Emacs starts.  If you really want to do this automatically, put it in your [`init.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

You can write your own function for DP2 and put it in `my/init`.  There are plenty of good tutorials on the net.  If you get any specific question, ask it here on Emacs Slack Exchange.

```lisp
(setq my/init-shell-vterm-name "my_buffer_name")
(setq my/init-shell-dirs '("~/src/emacs" "~/src/linux"))
(defun my/init-shells (dirs)
  (progn
    (tab-bar-new-tab)
    (shell (expand-file-name (car dirs)))
    
    (tab-bar-new-tab)
    (let* ((default-directory (expand-file-name (cadr dirs)))
           (vterm-buffer-name my/init-shell-vterm-name)
           (buf (vterm)))
      (switch-to-buffer buf))))

(defun my/init ()
  (interactive)
  (my/init-shells my/init-shell-dirs))
```

You can create a frame with `make-frame` but I don't think there is a way to know which frame is on which display.  If someone know how to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has a built-in feature for this, called [deskto-save-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html).
It saves your buffer list and even the frame positions on your screens in a file so that when you close emacs and reopen it next time, everything is exactly as you left it. It even remembers which frames were on which screen.
Also check out the following link for more information:

[How to restore Emacs' windows and buffers from the last session?](https://superuser.com/questions/383560/how-to-restore-emacs-windows-and-buffers-from-the-last-session)

where another package is introduced as well.
Try it out and you will not want to miss it anymore

Comment: desktop-save-mode - not work correct. Given: "DP1 - frame with  open only one tab.
DP2 - frame with open 2 tabs.
DP3 - frame open 3 tabs". But after restart Emacs on the DP2 open 2 frames ,one overlaps the other. On DP1 open one frame. But on DP-3 not open frame.

Comment: Another big problem that desktop-save-mode not restore shell buffers. Before exit from Emacs it ask me: "Active processes exist; kill them and exist anyway?" I select yes. And after restart Emacs not show shell buffers. How fix this?

Comment: Concerning your first comment: Not really sure why it behaves like this: Also do you use tabs in emacs like in  [tab-bar-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode)?

Concerning the shell buffers, yeah, your're right. I didn't find a solution for this yet, so I start them manually each session, could be automated with a macro though, but it's no big deal for me since it's just a simple `M-x ansi-term`

Comment: Bemm Yes, I use tab-bar-mode

Comment: Bemm If I turn off "tab-bar mode" the result is same (incorrect). On DP-1 open 2 frames, on DP-2 open one frame, and on DP-3 not open any frame.